# Can't get Unity Firebase userID

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save the user data to the firebase realtime database directly after the user has been created. But the problem is not the saving, but the UserID. I save also save the user ID that i get from CurrentUser. and then i check in the realtime database and saw that the ID that stored was from a last user who recently created. And i check it in the editor by getting the current user Email and it showed the last user Email not the current user who are creating at the moment. Can someone help me to get the current user ID and not the last user id.
You guys can see the image from the links.
[What ID should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHsSB.png)
[The last user ID showing up instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VIQt.png) You guys can see that the ID don't event match. I did try redo the project and looking at the videos that from firebase it self. I really have no ide what to do, i am stuck for 3 days now.

```
public void SaveNewUserInCode(string userId, string Name, string Email) {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
    string userNameId;
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        userNameId = currentUser.Email;
        user = new User(userId, Name, Email);
        string Json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
        reference.Child("Users").Child(currentUser.UserId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(Json);
        Data.text = userNameId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the code that invokes `SaveNewUserInCode`.

I see a few potential dangers with the code you've posted:

The first is that any call (other than `Auth.SignOut`) is asynchronous. If you're caching `userId` immediately after `Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync`, you'll likely have the previous user still in `Auth.CurrentUser` (until the related task completes). See [my related post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) on all the ways to wait for a task in Unity if you think this is the issue.

The second, especially if Email is sometimes null, you may be automatically calling `Auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync` every time your app starts (perhaps old logic, I usually start my prototypes with anonymous users and later on add real accounts when it's time to do some user testing). This will always overwrite your current user *even if you were previously signed in anonymously*. You should always check `Auth.CurrentUser` before calling any of the `Auth.SignIn` methods, but definitely make sure that you don't have a stray `Auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync` laying around.

If the issue is threading, I believe the following logic will fix your problem:

```
var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
    // omitted : any error handling. Check task's state
    var user = task.Result;
    SaveNewUserInCode(user.UserId, user.DisplayName /* or however you get Name */, user.Email);
});
```